# can not hit the SerialDataReceivedEvent?

Tags: c#, serial-port

All these comes from the idea that i want to use the **SerialPort class** in .Net , but the only way is  by calling dll . Because i can only get interfaces from the program calling this dll. mycode is below.

i wrote a class about serialport,

```
public class CommClass
{
    public SerialPort _port;
    private string _receivedText;
    public string receivedText
    {
        get { return _receivedText; }
        set
        {
            _receivedText = value;
        }
    }
    public CommClass(string _pname)
    {
        portList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        _port = new SerialPort(portList[0]);
        if (portList.Length < 1)
            _port= null;
        else
        {
            if(portList.Contains(_pname.ToUpper()))
            { 
                _port = new SerialPort(_pname);
                _port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(com_DataReceived);
             }
        }
    }
    private  void com_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string indata = _port.ReadExisting();
        receivedText = indata;
    }
}
```

from **Bytestoread** i can see there r data coming in and  i can get data from port.**ReadExisting()**, but receivedText did not change ,it did not hit the **SerialDataReceived event** . Is my way wrong?any suggestion?thanks

i created a dll from CommClass ,then i call it in my winform program which has a button and a textbox . Clicking the button , then i initialize the port

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CommClass mycom;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       mycom = new CommClass("com3");
       mycom._port.Open();
       textbox.Text=mycom.receivedText;//i add a breakpoint at this line ,
    }
```

when hitting it , i check  mycom._port.PortName is "com3", its IsOpen() is "Open" , i use virtual port to send data . i send "1111",then check the `mycom._port.BytestoRead` is 4, and  `mycom._port.ReadExisting()` is "1111", but mycom.receivedText is null. My puzzle is that i have no idea when the data is coming . How to use the `DataReceived` event in my winform without code "**using System.Io.Ports**",just with reference `CommClass.dll`.  Did i make it clear?   Thanks for help.

Comment: Where do you check `BytesToRead`? Do you ever actually open the `SerialPort`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho,i check it in my buttonclick event , it did open .

Comment: Do you ever set `textbox.Text` again, or is your `button1_Click()` method the only place? How do you know "it did not hit the SerialDataReceived event"? It seems that you are not sharing all of the information relevant to your question -- missing code, not describing what debugging steps you've already taken, etc. -- which will make it very difficult to allow anyone to actually _help_. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   mycom._port.Open();
   textbox.Text=mycom.receivedText;//i add a breakpoint at this line ,
```

That code cannot work, it is a threading race bug.  The DataReceived event does not fire *instantly* after you open the port.  It will take a microsecond or so, give or take.  A threadpool thread has to get started to fire the event.  And of course the device actually has to send something, they usually only do so when you transmit something first.

Which clearly did not happen, your DataReceived event handler has a bug as well.  It is not allowed to update the Text property of a control in that event since it runs on a worker thread.  Your program will bomb with an InvalidOperationException.

You'll have to write something like this instead:

```
private void com_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string indata = _port.ReadExisting();
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
         textbox.AppendText(indata);
    }));
}
```

With the additional stipulation that you must not leave it this way, updating the Text property of a TextBox and making it visible on the screen is an expensive operation that's going to turn your user interface catatonic when the device starts transmitting data at a high rate.

Comment: thanks@Hans Passant, here [Serial Comms in C# for Beginners in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners). but my CommClass will be called after being created as dll , in this class `BeginInvoke` is not proper.

Comment: Well, use SynchronizationContext.Post().  Doesn't have much to do with SerialPort or this question.  Make this code work before you turn it into a library, you are not close yet.